# how to populate data at run time in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an angular app that needs to connect to the server and authorize from them before we retrieve data
The problem is the `{{}}` scope doesn't show the updated data that is retrieved from the server.

I have something like

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        'use strict';
        $scope.signIn = function() {        
            // Authenticate (takes a bout 2 second to get the data back
            server1.authenticate(uame, pd, function(data){
            //parse data
            $scope.data = data
            }            
            $scope.$broadcast('sData', $scope);
         }
})
.controller('mCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        'use strict';
        $scope.test='old test';
        $scope.$on('sData', function(event, nData){
            $scope.test=nData.test  //show 'new test' as a string
        })
})
```

html

```
<div ng-click='signIn'>click me</div>
{{test}} //shows 'old test' when first load. but not showing 'new test' after user click the div.
```

Can anyone help me about it? thanks so much!

Comment: you can try event.currentScope.test = nData.test

Comment: you'll probably need to use $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the Documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

This probably is due to the digest already happening.  I would either use:

```
$scope.$apply()
//or better
//use the scope returned in the listener
$scope.$on('sData', function(event, nData){
    event.currentScope.test = nData.test  //show 'new test' as a string
})
```

**$on(name, listener)**;
Listens on events of a given type. See $emit for discussion of event life cycle.

The event listener function format is: **function(event, args...)**. The event object passed into the listener has the following attributes:

**targetScope** - {Scope}: the scope on which the event was $emit-ed or $broadcast-ed.

**currentScope** - {Scope}: the current scope which is handling the event.

**name** - {string}: name of the event.

**stopPropagation** - {function=}: calling stopPropagation function will cancel further event 
propagation (available only for events that were $emit-ed).
preventDefault - {function}: calling preventDefault sets defaultPrevented flag to true.

**defaultPrevented** - {boolean}: true if preventDefault was called.